# Using Control Bus EIP in Spring Integration to start/stop channels dynamically

Tags: spring-integration, enterprise-integration, control-bus

I am interested in using Spring Integration to fetch files from various endpoints (FTP servers, email inboxes, S3, etc.) and load them into my system (essentially, ETL).

There are times when I will want these channels active and running, and other times when I will want them paused/stopped. Meaning, even if there are files available at the source, I do not want the channel consuming the data and doing anything with it.

Is a [control bus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/control-bus.html) an appropriate start/stop solution here:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from("controlBus")
              .controlBus()
              .get();
}
```

If so, how would I stop/restart a specific channel (route between an S3 bucket and the rest of my system) using the Java DSL/API? And if not, then what is the recommended practice/EIP to apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Control Bus is exactly a pattern and tool designed for your goal: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ControlBus.html.

Yes, to use it you need to send messages to input channel of that control bus endpoint. The payload of message to sent must be a command to do some control activity for endpoint. Typically we call start and stop.

So, let's imagine you have an S3 source polling channel adapter:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow s3Flow(S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource) {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource, e -> e.id("myS3SourceEndpoint"))
          ...;
}
```

So, to stop that `myS3SourceEndpoint` via Control Bus, you need to send a message with a payload `@myS3SourceEndpoint.stop()`.

Pay attention that we don't talk here about message channels neither message sources. The active components in the flow are really endpoints.

**UPDATE**

The Control Bus component utilizes a Command Message pattern. So, you need to build a respective message and send it to the input channel of that control bus endpoint. Something like this is OK:

```
@Autowired
MessageChannel controlBus;

...
this.controlBus.send(new GenericMessage<>("@myS3SourceEndpoint.stop()"));
```

You can use a `MessagingTemplate.convertAndSend()` if you don't like creating message yourself. Or you also can expose high-lever API via `@MessagingGateway` interface.

Everything you can find in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/index.html

Comment: Thank you! And I recognized your name from the Javadocs!

Comment: Hey @Artem any chance I could see a 1- or 2-line example of sending `@myS3SourceEndpoint.stop()` to a control bus?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.